# How can I change such a JSON parser?

Tags: javascript, json, web

please help me how to change such a parser to JSON for a new server response.

Old server response:

```
{"names":[{"name":"Oleg","act":0,"total":0},{"name":"Vitya","act":2,"total":2}]}
```

Old parser:

```
names = appData.filter( function(x) { return skipped.indexOf(x) < 0; })
        get("https://serv.io/set?" + names.join("|")).then(function(data) {
          result = JSON.parse(data)["names"]
          for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            name = result[i]["name"]
            act = result[i]["act"]
            total = result[i]["total"]
          }
```

New server response:

```
{"Oleg":{"act":0,"total":0},"Vitya":{"act":2,"total":2}}
```

As you can see in the new answer, as I understand it, there is no array and here the name is as the name of the object.
The question is how to change the old parser for the new server response.
I would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the keys on the object by [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Also [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is useful for this kind of data processing.

```js
const result = {"Oleg":{"act":0,"total":0},"Vitya":{"act":2,"total":2}}

for (const key in result) {
  const name = key
  const {act, total} = result[key]
  
  console.log(name, act, total)
}
```

Please note that `for..in` iteration doesn't preserve the order of elements contained in the returned JSON.

> There is no guarantee that `for...in` will return the indexes in any particular order.

(from the `for..in` reference mentioned above.)

If the order of the elements is important to your system, you need to consider using another JSON parser instead of the built-in `JSON.parse()` method.

Comment: Do you know about [snippets?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) (You don't need the fiddle.)

Comment: @msanford didn't know that. I updated my answer with a snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simulating the new response server:

```
// New server response
const data = JSON.stringify({"Oleg":{"act":0,"total":0},"Vitya":{"act":2,"total":2}})

// Assuming that you have already the variables declared
let name;
let act;
let total;

// Parse the JSON and work with it
const result = JSON.parse(data)

// Save this result in a variable, to avoid use Object.entries everywhere.
const names = Object.entries(result);

// This will be your new loop
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  name = names[i][0];
  act = names[i][1].act;
  total = names[i][1].total
  console.log(name, act, total);
}
```

This will be the output every time in the loop:

```
Oleg 0 0
Vitya 2 2
```